# What is wrong with this Scala recursive code?

Tags: scala, recursion, fibonacci

I have recently started learning Scala and trying to implement a recursive function in it. My goal for this exercise is to return the nth number in the fibonacci series.

```
def fib(n: Int ): Int = {

  def go(n:Int, prev:Int, curr: Int, res:Int): Int =
    if (n == 0 ) res
    else go(n-1, curr, prev+curr, prev+curr)

    go (n, 0, 1, 0 )
}

def main(args: Array[String]): Int =
  println(fib(7))
```

There are no compilation errors, however the result comes as open and close parenthesis.

Result--> ()

Any advise.

Comment: please elaborate, what have done , and where are you stuck at etc.. stackOverFlow does not encourage `how-to-do-this` type of question ..

Comment: Execution of this code results in open and close parenthesis [my result : ()].

Comment: You never call `go` from `fib`. `fib` does not return anything, it has return type `Unit`. Your base case for the recursive call is 7, which is definitely not one of the two base cases for the Fibonacci series.

Comment: `go (n, 0, 1, 0 )` should be outside the method `go`.

Comment: @JithinScaria. I may be new here but I know what kind of questions people ask in stackOverFlow. So If you don't know the answer or willing to help, then you do not have to jump the gun and try to put comment on every question.

Comment: @RandomnessSlayer and Sarvesh: Thanks for your inputs, I will work on it.

Comment: @Ira, I see that you are trying to implement your function in a more functional programming style and you have already resolved your issue. My one quick suggestion would be to not hard code 10 as well. For testing it is ok, still I would suggest to not to hard code it. Think it from production point of view.

Comment: Thank you! I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I got this.

Here is how I have done.

```
def fib(n: Int ) : Int = {    
 def go(n: Int, prev: Int, curr: Int, res: Int): Int =     

 if (n == 0 ) res     
 else go(n-1, curr, prev+curr, prev+curr)     

 go (n-2, 0, 1, 0 )
}
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = 
   println(fib(10))
```